# Problema para converter ANSI para UTF-8 em Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho alguns arquivos que estão com codificação ANSI e com acentos, "ç" e tudo mais. 
Preciso converter esses vários arquivos para codificação UTF-8.
Alguns arquivos ficam com codificação UTF-8 e outros não, por que?

O código que uso é o seguinte:

```
import codecs

def encode_files(self):
    path_list_files = glob.glob(self.config.path_prepared_scd + r"\*.txt")

    for path_files in path_list_files:
        file = path_files.split("\\")[-1].split(".")[0]
        output_temp = self.config.path_temp_scd + "\\" + file + ".tmp"

        with codecs.open(path_files, "r", encoding="ANSI", errors="ignore") as text_reading:
            content = text_reading.read()
        with codecs.open(output_temp, "w", encoding="UTF-8", errors="ignore") as text_writing:
            text_writing.write(content)
```

Por que alguns ficam corretamente como UTF-8 e outros não?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O que é "não ficar corretamente"? Se você não mostrar o que está errado, não tem como dizer o certo.

Na verdade,  "codificação ANSI" nem é um padrão só - no Python, só é válida no Windows, e dá erro em outros sistemas, e indica a codificação padrão do Windows em que o programa está rodando. Pegue o seu mesmo programa, mesmo arquivo de dados, e rode num C na Ucrânia, e tenha resultados diferentes! Já que você sabe em qual codificação os arquivos estão (se são mostrados corretamente numa máquina com Windows em português), use o nome da codificação fixa:  "latin-1". (Daí, se você leva seus dados e o mesmo programa pra outro PC, um na nuvem, por exemplo, ele ainda executa corretamente).

Continuando, colocar "errors='ignore'" aí é uma péssima prática - e não vai dar em nada: pra codificação "latin-1" todos os bytes são válidos, então nunca haverá um erro de decoding, e, por outro lado, para a codificação em UTF-8, todos os caractéres do Unicode são válidos, então também nunca vai dar erro. **mas** se **houvesse** algum erro, tudo o que seria conseguido com o ignore é que você teria dados omitidos da saída, e nunca saberia sobre eles - os caracteres seriam simplesmente suprimidos, sem nenhuma notificação do programa, nem nada. Veja esse exemplo forçando caracteres com acento em uma codificação que não os aceita:

```
In [4]: "maçã".encode("ASCII", errors="ignore")                                                                                    
Out[4]: b'ma'
```

**Por fim**, mas sem dar certeza, já que você não diz *o quê* está errado, o que posso imaginar é que alguns dos arquivos que você está tentando converer pra UTF-8 já *estejam* em utf-8. Nesse caso, você vai ter uma codificação dupla - os caracteres acentuados vão aparecer como dois caracteres (se tivesse uma amostra de como está o erro, seria possível dar certeza disso). Ou isso, ou, de qualquer forma, os arquivos de entrada estão com uma codificação diferente da esperada.

No caso de alguns arquivos já estarem em utf-8, uma forma simples de se evitar a codificação dupla, é ler o arquivo em utf-8 antes, e apenas em caso de erro ler o arquivo com a codificação latin-1 -

Dá para fazer:

```
from pathlib import Path

def encode_files(self):
    folder = Path(self.config.path_prepared_scd)

    for path_files in folder.glob("*.txt"):
        output = folder / (path_files.stem + ".tmp")
        try:
            data = path_files.read_text(encoding="utf-8")
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            data = path_files.read_text(encoding="latin-1")

        output.write_text(data, encoding="utf-8")
```

O uso de pathlib.Path facilita muito também a  manipulação de nomes de arquivo e diretórios - além de prover os métodos `read_text` e `write_text`, que pra casos em que o arquivo vai ser transferido todo de uma vez, ficam mais simples do que usar "open", "with", etc...

Comment: Muito Obrigado. Funcionou perfeitamente e ficou muito mais limpo o código. Não conhecia esse procedimento.
Grato mais uma vez @jsbueno